# Assigning to two pointers at the same time in C

Tags: c, assign

I have a small segment of C code that I am a bit confused about.

```
int *p, *q, arr[4]={5,8,3,7}
p = q = arr;
```

Does the pointer assignment mean both `p` and `q` equal `arr`? Or that `p` equals `q` which equals `arr`? This has been bugging me for a while, any help appreciated

Comment: A <10 line test program can settle this for you and you'll remember it a lot more than someone spoon feeding you the answer.

Comment: Try `printf (" p: %p\n q: %p\n", p, q);` following the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment operator (`=`) is right associative. This means

```
a = b = c;
```

parses as

```
a = (b = c);
```

That is, the value of `c` is assigned to `b`, and the result value of this assignment operation is assigned to `a`.

The `=` operator is defined to return the value that was assigned, so this effectively sets both `a` and `b` to `c`.

Answer (score 0):

`p` and `q` both end up pointing to `arr` (or more properly `&arr[0]`, it makes a difference in more advanced scenarios). Both of the ways you phrase it are equivalent when dealing with value semantics as is the case when dealing with pointer values in C.

More generally, in C the `=` operator produces as it's value the value assigned to it's left-hand operand so you can chain assignments of any type that can be assigned.